# Using nor only with verb of being

Tags: negation

Is emphasized part of this sentence correct?

> Fact that apartment building floats on water–it’s an ark, is not exposed in the beginning. **Nor it is for the longer part of the narration.**

Comment: Welcome to ELL. We can give you a better quality answer if you explain why you think your sentence might not be correct. What are your concerns anout it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The emphasized sentence is, as such, grammatically correct. (It is a full sentence.)

I would opt for *better* instead of *longer*, but that is probably a matter of taste.

Although you don't ask about it, the first sentence *does* raise some concerns.

For starters, I'm missing some *articles*, and that makes for a confusing sentence. The confusion is further enhance by your unbalanced use of the em-dash. I would write the first sentence as:

> The fact that the apartment building floats on water — it’s an ark — is not exposed in the beginning.